# TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Tags: python, tkinter

I was working on an autoclicker with a gui when I ran into this problem: TypeError: **call**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Not sure how to fix it, I've tried everything

Full code: https://codeshare.io/axY39N

```
Label(window, text="Tan AutoClicker", fg="white", bg="#1589d6", font="none 
20", width=30).grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(window, text="Keybind:", fg="white", bg="#1589d6", font="none 
10").grid(row=3, column=0)
binding = Entry(window, bg="white", width=10)
binding.grid(row=4, column=0)
Button (window, text="Submit", width=6, height=1, 
command=set_keybind).grid(row=5, column=0)
```

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted the complete stacktrace, I'm guessing this is the issue, in your code you have

```
from tkinter import *
# ...
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
```

Later on you had

```
Button (window, text="Submit", width=6, height=1, command=set_keybind).grid(row=5, column=0)
```

So, I think the `Button` is actually a `pynput.mouse.Button`, not `tkinter.Button` as you expected, and `pynput.mouse.Button` is confused with the extra arguments (`text` to be exact).

That's one reason to avoid doing `from package import *`, apart from the readability misconceptions.

Comment: So what would I change from tkinter import * to?

Comment: you can do `import tkinter as tk` and then instead of `Button`, do `tk.Button`, etc. and do that for the other widgets...

Comment: Then why I try to do tk.configure or chance the window title it said it's not defined.

Comment: for the `title` and `configure` methods, you aren't supposed to do that, they are methods of `window` which happens to be a `Tk()`. So, bottom line is, only `window = Tk()` will be changed to `window = tk.Tk()`.